# Page size fixed width in middle

Tags: html, css

I am not sure what it's called, but can someone tell me how I can make a CSS style sheet that makes all pages fit within a given width, and then adds a drop shadow type effect, making it look like a page?

Something like this:
http://www.news.com.au/

So, you have the white (or grey, or what ever) borders on the sides, and the content is placed within the 'borders'.

Edit:
I have tried this style, but it put's the box in the top left corner:

```
style>
    html, body {
        background-color: #F0F0F0;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: small;

    }

    #wrapper {
        background-color: #fff;
        width: 920px;
        padding: 20px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px#888;
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px #888;
    }
</style>
```

And my usage is:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <h1>Location Search</h1>

    <h2>Simple Lookup</h2>

    ....

</div>
```

Comment: It's a background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be an image but you can make something like that with box-shadow.

I think it's just a wrapper with a width of 960px and margin: 0 auto; and a bit of box-shadow. so something like this:

CSS:

```
html,body{
background-color: #F0F0F0; // a little darker then the wrapper.
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrapper{
background-color: #fff;
width: 920px; // because of padding.
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 20px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px#888;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
}
```

and a html like this.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper"> // you just put this div around all of your other divs so it makes it one big div.

...
Some divs for the layout.
...

</div>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Kees. Nailed it. Not sure why I got all the neg votes though. But thanks. Answered.

Comment: Is there a good way to center the box on the screen? horiz-align: center; in the body?

Comment: which box? when you give it a width of 960px and a margin: 0 auto i should center in the middle.

Comment: OK, in Chrome, the box is good - but, left aligned... http://www.listerhome.com

Comment: please show your code. what you have so far.

Comment: see my edit :) i think that will fix it. note that i editted the html,body

Comment: I added the code, which simple moves the box into the top left corner. I have edited my question, with the code I am trying.